# jQuery UI Autocomplete not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out. I'm trying to make the jQuery UI Autocomplete function work properly. I have 3 instructors defined as the following:

```
    var Instructors = [
        {id: "1", name:"Jamie O’Neil", first:"Jamie", last:"O’Neil", email: "jamie@email.com"},
        {id: "2", name:"Jerry Stenger", first:"Jerry", last:"Stenger", email: "jerry@email.com"},
        {id: "3", name:"John Henderson", first:"John", last:"Henderson", email: "john@email.com"}
    ];
```

Then I have an HTML form with first name, last name, email. When I type into the first name field "Jer" I want to see the suggestion for "Jerry", but instead the suggestions disappear. If I delete my input I see all options, so it is **partially** working. Full code is below. See my JSFiddle here for working demo of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/jsargent4039/j325zkqs/2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.0em;
        }
        input {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.0em;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( function() {
        var Instructors = [
            {id: "1", name:"Jamie O’Neil", first:"Jamie", last:"O’Neil", email: "jamie@email.com"},
            {id: "2", name:"Jerry Stenger", first:"Jerry", last:"Stenger", email: "jerry@email.com"},
            {id: "3", name:"John Henderson", first:"John", last:"Henderson", email: "john@email.com"}
        ];
        
        $( "#first_name" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: Instructors,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#first_name" ).val( ui.item.first );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#first_name").val(ui.item.first);
            $("#last_name").val(ui.item.last);
            $("#email").val(ui.item.email);
            return false;
        }
        })
        .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li>" )
            .append( '<div title="' + item.first +' ' + item.last + '">' + item.first + ' </div></li>' )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
    } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <p><input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="First" value="" /></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Last" value="" /></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="" /></p>
        <p><input type="reset" id="BtnReset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The Source Data, when an Object, must include `label` and `value` properties. You can have more than these two, yet these two must be included. See: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: Thank you so much for that tip. I will give that a try.

Comment: OK, yes, this fixes the problem I was having. Thanks so much!